# Is there a way to animate colour of an image from left to right?

Tags: css, angular, sass, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a loading icon using an image. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the image animate between two colours from left to right infinitely. This is done in Angular 7. I'm new to animations but as far as I understand I can solve this with CSS animations.

What I want is something similar to the example below. Only I want the grayscale to disappear to the right, and instead of a grayscale I want to pick two different colours.

All help is appreciated!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.effect {
  position: relative;
}

.effect-dup {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  animation: width 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes width {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
  <div class='effect-dup'><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" /></div>
</div>

<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" />
  <div class='effect-dup'>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `filter: grayscale(100%)` to the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) you want...

Comment: You can use CSS animations or you can use Angular based animations : https://angular.io/guide/animations.  Always nice to have options :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the fast reply! So let's say I've managed to get the filters that I want. How can I then change between two filters in the animation?

Comment: It's already animating the change between no filter and a filter. So add a filter to the initial state (`.effect`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider an extra layer and [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). Simply adjust the coloration and the blending to obtain the color you want. You will no more need to duplicate the image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.effect {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.effect:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: width 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  background: linear-gradient(blue,red);
}

@keyframes width {
  from {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
</div>

<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what OP was looking for or not, but it definitely looks awesome 

Comment: In addition to @Temani answer, to run indefinitely, you can use `  animation-iteration-count: infinite;` css property

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've tried your solution with cobra's addition, but then I get a jumping animation. I would like the filter to disappear to the side and appear on the other side. Is this doable?

Comment: @kebbaben add `alternate` to the animation : `animation: width 5s ease-in-out infinte alternate;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif That only create a bouncy effect. I want an animation to appear on the left side and disappear on the right side and then do it again, like a loop.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes that's exactly what I want! Although I forgot that the image I want to apply this to uses transparency. Is there a way to do this **only** where there is no transparency?

Comment: @kebbaben I don't think it's possible but you can ask this as a separate question. avoid asking a lot of different question at the same time as it would hard for other people to help since this discussion is hidden in the comment section. You can consider my code as a starting point for another question and I am sure you will get some ideas (I will also think about)

Comment: Sounds reasonable! Accepted as answer.